# Unity Speech Recognition C# dictionary problem

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I want to successfully implement an advanced speech recognition system that can know what to do if you speak a phrase of 2 or 3 actions like "GO FORWARD and CHANGE COLOR TO GREEN and then TURN TO THE LEFT". I've implemented a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action[]> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action[]>();
```

and by now I added some words in it:

```
actions.Add("up", new Action[] { Up });
actions.Add("down", new Action[] { Down });
actions.Add("left", new Action[] { Left });
actions.Add("right", new Action[] { Right });
actions.Add("green", new Action[] { () => ChangeColor(this.word) });
actions.Add("red", new Action[] { () => ChangeColor(this.word) });
actions.Add("white", new Action[] { () => ChangeColor(this.word) });
actions.Add("blue", new Action[] { () => ChangeColor(this.word) });
actions.Add("yellow", new Action[] { () => ChangeColor(this.word) });
```

But then I thought...

I want to have advanced speech recognition, so I think (and I hope!) there is a better way than adding lots and lots of combinations of words in this dictionary.

So can you help me? Do you know if there is a better way? Because it would be very unpleasant and boring and it would take a long long time to get in the dictionary what you want. Even for changing color, I can think now at: change color to green, change to green, change your color to green, make green your color, make green your new color, etc.

Comment: its not phrase but keyword recognition...its little different..its done to understant small command keyword,

Comment: Okayyy... and how would it be possible? What do I need to look into? Just point me in a direction:)

Comment: just this functionality exist in unity..but i have a solution to help you to code with a best way and easier..just some time before answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you to code easier, you could use this method:

so using enum to list your command and inject automatically in the Recognizer. the advantage of this method : if you add new commands no big modification in your code, just add new funtionality.. so i think the program is more readable.

```
public class TestPrg : MonoBehaviour
{
    private enum Commands
    {
        Up = 0, Forward, Left, Right,//first group
        Green, Blue, Red,            //second group
        Other, Other1                //third group....
    }

    private KeywordRecognizer kr; 

    void Start()
    {
        //Transform Enum Commands to string[]    
        kr = new KeywordRecognizer(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Commands)));

        kr.OnPhraseRecognized += RecognizedSpeech;
        kr.Start();
    }


    private void RecognizedSpeech(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs speech)
    {
        Commands cmd;
        if (Enum.TryParse(speech.text, true, out cmd))
        {
            ActionCmd(cmd);
        }
    }

    private void ActionCmd(Commands cmd)
    {
        if (cmd >= Commands.Up && cmd <= Commands.Right)
        {
            Move(cmd);
        }
        else if (cmd >= Commands.Green && cmd <= Commands.Red)
        {
            ChangeColor(cmd);
        }
        else
        {
                //Othercommand();
        }
    }

    void Move(Commands cmd)
    {
        switch (cmd)
        {
            case Commands.Up:
                //action
                break;
            case Commands.Forward:
                //action
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ChangeColor(Commands cmd)
    {
        switch (cmd)
        {
            case Commands.Green:
                //action
                break;
            case Commands.Blue:
                //action
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it's much better than my code. I will use it right away:) Thank you, Frenchy :)

Comment: Hey, I forgot to ask you something, if you don't mind. If I want to combine for example two colors. I say "yellow and red"  and my target should change color to orange. More generally, how can I remember the words before cmd?

Comment: you could try the keyword "YellowandRed" or "yellowred" avoid space, in anyway enum doesnt like space in name...after you could try to put space in keyword..dunno if recognizer is good with that..but that need to adapt the solution with other thing than enum

Comment: Alright, thank you for your response. I really do appreciate it! I'll think about it and I'll come to a solution if I need to adapt my code or not. Thanks again!